# Need some algebra explaination for hyperbolic sinus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am reading a book where i have come across an expression:

$$
\frac{e^{x}\left(-a^2+b^2+2iab\right)- e^{-x}\left(-a^2 +b^2-2iab\right)}{2}
$$

In the book they state that we can express this equation in terms of hyperbolic sin like this:

$$
\sinh x\cdot \left(-a^2+b^2\right)
$$

**It is not so obvious to me how they do this although i know the definition of hyperbolic sine...**

---

Then they just rewrite first equation like this:

$$
\frac{e^{-x}\left(a^2 -b^2+2iab\right) +e^{x}\left(-a^2+b^2+2iab\right)}{2}
$$

I understand this, but then again they express the above in terms ofhyperbolic cosine like this:

$$
\cosh x\cdot \left(2iab\right)
$$

**Again, it is not obvious to me how they do this... Could someone please point that out?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions) $$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2,\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2,$$

$$
\frac{e^{-x}\left(a^2 -b^2+2iab\right) +e^{x}\left(-a^2+b^2+2iab\right)}{2}
$$

$$=-(a^2-b^2)\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2\right)+2abi\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\right)$$

$$=-(a^2-b^2)\sinh(x)+2abi \cosh(x)$$